# How to fix html table row span in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, html-table

I am facing a problem with table rowspan dynamically. I have tried but it does not work properly.

I have a array json. I have bind a table with angular 6 for loop. I want to show Faculty, Study Campus MC, Study Campus PC and Total header with row span.
I have tried to show Study Campus MC, Study Campus PC and Total as i want but some unnecessary rows shows in the right side of the column.

My output table:
[image]

I want as like this table: 
[image]

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/table-rowspan-angular?file=src/app/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to archive this, I suggest you to change your json object format like this.

```
testJson = [
    {
        "shortName": "FHSS",
        "children": [
            {
                "physicallyApply": 1,
                "onlineApply": 0,
                "semesterName": "Summer",
                "semesterYear": 2020,
                "programName": "B.A. in English",
                "studyCampus": "Main Campus",
                "programTotal": 1
            },
            {
                "physicallyApply": 0,
                "onlineApply": 7,
                "semesterName": "Summer",
                "semesterYear": 2020,
                "programName": "B.A. in English",
                "studyCampus": "Permanent Campus",
                "programTotal": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "shortName": "FSIT",
        "children": [
            {
                "physicallyApply": 1,
                "onlineApply": 2,
                "semesterName": "Summer",
                "semesterYear": 2020,
                "programName": "B. Sc. in Multimedia and Creative Technology",
                "studyCampus": "Main Campus",
                "programTotal": 3
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Then you have to change your HTML like this.

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Faculty</th>
        <th>Program</th>
        <th>Physically Apply</th>
        <th>Online Apply</th>
        <th>Program Total</th>
        <th>Study Campus MC</th>
        <th>Study Campus PC</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of testJson; let i = index">

        <tr *ngFor="let child of item.children; let x = index;">
          <td >{{x == 0 ? item.shortName : null}}</td>
          <td>{{child.programName}}</td>
          <td>{{child.physicallyApply}}</td>
          <td>{{child.onlineApply}}</td>
          <td>{{child.programTotal}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="x==0 && i==0" [attr.rowspan]="i">{{totalMC}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="x==0 && i==0" [attr.rowspan]="i">{{totalPC}}</td>
          <td *ngIf="x==0 && i==0" [attr.rowspan]="i">{{totalMC + totalPC}}</td>
        </tr>
  </ng-container>
    </tbody>                
 </table>
```

CHeck it here: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4re8dd)

Comment: It is not working properly. Can you please provide a example in stackblitz

Comment: Is there possible to merge row of faculty as i have shown in the image. Otherwise your answer is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing `totalMC, totalPC and totalMC + totalPC` more than once (due to looping). You have to make sure that, they are going to appear only once using `ngIf` like below -

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of testJson; let i = index">
    <td>{{item.shortName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.programName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.physicallyApply}}</td>
    <td>{{item.onlineApply}}</td>
    <td>{{item.programTotal}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="i==0" [attr.rowspan]="i">{{totalMC}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="i==0" [attr.rowspan]="i">{{totalPC}}</td>
    <td *ngIf="i==0" [attr.rowspan]="i">{{totalMC + totalPC}}</td>
  </tr>
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/table-rowspan-angular-qrncil)

Comment: @Rashid my country brother thanks. Your solution is ok but another problem Faculty row span is still now........

Comment: You can use appropriate condition on that :)